# whats the difference between putting a model in app vs in module?

Tags: yii

I am trying to understand the reasoning to this. Should I be concerned if my module is accessing the models from the app and not from it's own model? Should all modules have its own models?

Sorry if it's a newbie question but I would really like to understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It totally depends on your application. If you have models that are only being used by one module and only one, it is logical that you put those models inside the module itself.

However, if your models are shared between modules and/or are application-wide, then you should put it in the main `models` folder

Answer (score 0):

you can access protected/model in module,widgets,there is no need to put the models under module/model directory.

[See More detail](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.module)